# Telegram Bot GetUpdates generate exception

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

My bot worked some years but some time ago it stopped working.
I have debugged it and detected the place:
This line generates an exception

var updates = Bot.GetUpdates(updr);

> e = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
>   Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in TeleBotDotNet.dll

```
public void Process()
{
    bStop = false;
    try
    {
        var updr = new GetUpdatesRequest
        {
            Offset = _lastUpdateId + 1,
            Timeout = UpdateTimeoutInSeconds
        };
        var updates = Bot.GetUpdates(updr);

        if (updates.Result.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var update in updates.Result)
            {
                ProcessUpdate(update);
                _lastUpdateId = update.UpdateId;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        WriteLog("Exception occured!");
        WriteLog(e.Message);
    }
}
```

What happened and how to fix it?

Comment: hi, two things: 
one) can you post the complete stacktrace?

two) when did your bot stop working, and especially. was it on february 6th? because that was when telegram stopped accepting TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1

Comment: three) can you reproduce the bug using a different framework (for example https://www.nuget.org/packages/nerderies.TelegramBotApi/ ), if so, it might be the TLS problem, which is not a bug in the TeleBotApi, but in the executing .net runtime

Comment: It stopped to work in 2019

Comment: Also, my Smartphone is broken with SIM, but I have created the bot in this Telegram. It seems I need to create the new bot and re-make the bot code